# Prove The Orthogonal Complement of an Intersection is the Sum of Orthogonal Complements

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

How does one prove that $(A∩B)^⊥=A^⊥+B^⊥$?

Seems a bit harder than proving $(A+B)^⊥=A^⊥∩B^⊥$.

Comment: It is not completely clear what you are talking about. Please add more context; like, what are $A$ and $B$ - vector spaces?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Presumably, $A, B$ are subspaces of some (finite-dimensional) vector space $\Bbb V$, and $\perp$ is the orthogonal complement w.r.t. some inner product on $\Bbb V$.

**Hint** We can write the nominally easier second identity as
$$(C + D)^{\perp} = C^{\perp} \cap D^{\perp}.$$
Then, set $C = A^{\perp}$ and $D = B^{\perp}$.

Comment: Can't vote you up due to lack of reputation. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found this helpful.