# If $A\cap B=\left\{ 0\right\} $ and $A,B,A+B$ are closed, do we have $A^{\bot }+B^{\bot }=\left\{ 0\right\} ^{\bot }$?

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

If $A$ and $B$ are two closed subspaces of a Hilbert space, such that $A\cap B=\left\{ 0\right\} $ and $A+B$ is closed, do we have $A^{\bot }+B^{\bot }=\left\{ 0\right\} ^{\bot }$ ?

I'm confident with this statement since it becomes true if $A+B=\left\{ 0\right\} ^{\bot }$. I think that in the general case, all it remains is to add $(A+B)^{\bot}$ after finding orthogonals in $A+B$, that's what I'm trying to do but I'm not sifficiently confident with my reasonning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove The Orthogonal Complement of an Intersection is the Sum of Orthogonal Complements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1171777/prove-the-orthogonal-complement-of-an-intersection-is-the-sum-of-orthogonal-comp)

Comment: Subspaces of what?

Comment: Of a Hilbert space

Comment: @AnneBauval It is not that trivial in the infinite-dimensional case. E.g. look at what would happen in an infinite-dimensional inner product space: [Does $S^\bot+T^\bot = (S\cap T)^\bot$ hold in infinite-dimensional spaces?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/899273/does-s-bott-bot-s-cap-t-bot-hold-in-infinite-dimensional-spaces) (Note that the requirement of $A+B$ being closed is missing from that post. This requirement is [crucial](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/135547/998803), however.)

Comment: I agree, the closedness of the sum in infinite dimension is a very delicate point, so I regret  it has been bypassed in the selection of answer...

Comment: And (to answer to the recent edit) the extra assumption $A+B=\left\{ 0\right\} ^{\bot }$ does not help. "It is not that trivial" that $A^\bot+B^\bot$ is closed (and that "this statement becomes true"), even if $A+B=\left\{ 0\right\} ^{\bot }.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, if $A,B,A+B$ are closed subspaces of a Hilbert space $H$, then $A^{\bot }+B^{\bot }=(A\cap B)^{\bot }$.

Let us only prove that $(A\cap B)^{\bot }\subset A^{\bot }+B^{\bot }$ (the reverse inclusion being obvious).

Remark first that the canonical linear continuous bijection $A/(A\cap B)\to(A+B)/B$ is bicontinuous by the [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(functional_analysis)).

Let $y\in(A\cap B)^{\bot }.$ By the previous remark, the map $f:x\mapsto\langle y,x\rangle$ induces a continuous linear form $g$ on $A+B$, such that $g(B)=0$ and $g$ coincides with $f$ on $A.$ By Hahn-Banach's theorem, $g$ extends to some continuous linear form on $H$, i.e. $g(x)=\langle b,x\rangle$ for some $b\in H.$

Since $g(B)=0$, we have $b\in B^\bot$. And since $(f-g)(A)=0$, we have $a:=y-b\in A^\bot.$

Thus, any $y\in(A\cap B)^\bot$ can be written $y=a+b$ with $a\in A^\bot$ and $b\in B^\bot,$ q.e.d.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: How do you prove that $A^{\perp}+B^{\perp}$ is closed?

Comment: Mrs. Bauval you expressed doubts about the closedness of the sum, but I see that you are taking it as true in your proof! What is correct and what is not??

Comment: Please give us a reference or a proof for the statement of the first two lines of your proof.

Comment: I do not "take the closedness of the sum as true". The first sentence of my answer announces what I shall prove ($A^{\bot }+B^{\bot }=(A\cap B)^{\bot }$). The closedness of the LHS is an obvious corollary but is never used in my proof.

Comment: @DjalalOunadjela instead of thanking for an answer in a comment, the prefered way is to vote on it and/or accept it: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers